# how to properly realloc memory?

Tags: c, pointers

for my program, I'm trying to realloc memory so that I can add another person to a database. However, I keep receiving **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** errors once I enter the first name of the new entry.

```
void addRecord (char **firstName, char **lastName, double *scores, int *numberPeople) {
int i;
char **newFirstName, **newLastName;
double *newScores;

*numberPeople += 1; // adds person to total number of people

newFirstName = (char**) realloc(firstName,*numberPeople*sizeof(char*));
newLastName = (char**) realloc(lastName,*numberPeople*sizeof(char*));
newScores = (double*) realloc(scores,1*sizeof(double));

for (i = *numberPeople - 1; i < *numberPeople; i++) {
    newFirstName[i] = (char*) realloc(firstName, MAXIMUM_DATA_LENGTH*sizeof(char)); // MAXIMUM_DATA_LENGTH = 50
    newLastName[i] = (char*) realloc(lastName, MAXIMUM_DATA_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
}


printf("Adding New Person....\n\n");

for (i = *numberPeople - 1; i < *numberPeople; i++) {
    printf("First Name of new person: ");
    scanf("%s", newFirstName[i]); // EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_l386_GPFLT)

    printf("Last Name of new person: ");
    scanf("%s", newLastName[i]);

    printf("Score of new person: ");
    scanf("%lf", &newScores[i]);
}
```

I can only assume that I'm not correctly reallocating the memory. I'm still relatively new to C coming from Java, so my skill level on pointers is pretty low. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your compiler is complaining about using the return value of `malloc()` (or `realloc()`) without a conversion you are not using a (properly configured standard compliant) C compiler (or you are missing `#include <stdlib.h>`).

Comment: @pmg I am using the most up-to-date version of xcode and I have included the `stdlib.h` header. So yea, I'm not sure what is up...

Comment: Looks like you are using a C++ compiler. I suggest using a properly configured C compiler and not mixing the two languages. The differences between them can cause problems where there should be none. Your issue with the memory allocation is probably not related to the choice of C or C++ compiler though.

Comment: @pmg: he's just put in an unnecessary cast. He's not saying he's seeing a warning / error without it.

Comment: For a start you can just use fixed-size arrays. Today's computers have so much memory that you can just define arrays with, say, 1000 entries of names 100 chars long each. The only thing you have to get straight then is the counter of persons. The *next* step is finding a suitable allocation strategy. By the way, I would strongly suggest to use a struct to keep all data of a person, and have just one array with person structs as elements (instead of n arrays of strings, where a person's data is scattered over many such arrays).

Answer (score 0):

As a general point, compile with all warnings enabled (`-Wall`) and ensure you get no warnings. Secondly, simplify your approach (see below). Thirdly, you need `valgrind` to detect your pointer (mis)use errors.

There seem to be far more complexity here than necessary.

For instance in this bit:

```
for (i = *numberPeople - 1; i < *numberPeople; i++) {
    newFirstName[i] = (char*) realloc(firstName, MAXIMUM_DATA_LENGTH*sizeof(char)); // MAXIMUM_DATA_LENGTH = 50
    newLastName[i] = (char*) realloc(lastName, MAXIMUM_DATA_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
}
```

In each iteration, you are calling `realloc()` with `firstName` as the argument. That frees the data at `firstName` and allocates a new data set of a different size. That's fine (in theory) on the first pass through, but on the second pass through is going to free something that's already been freed. Same with `lastName`. Moreover `firstName` and `lastName` don't point to individual entries, they point to the arrays themselves, so this is wrong. IE on each pass of your loop dealing with individual entries of the arrays, you are freeing the whole array.

Next why does this `for` loop iterate over `i = *numberPeople - 1; i < *numberPeople`? That's always one entry.

Also *check the return from `realloc()`*. What happens if (e.g.) your array was not properly `malloc()`d before you call `realloc()` the first time?

Another issue is that you pass the arrays as `char **` to this function. But you then modify the location of the arrays. On return, the new location of the array is being lost.

It's very difficult to see what you are trying to do here. I recommend you use a much simpler approach:

- Expand the array,
- read your three variables into the final elements

No need for `for` loops.

Here's a simple rework. I have not tested this as you didn't provide a minimal complete verifiable example, but it should help you.

```
// note we use char*** as these are pointers to an array of char *
void
addRecord (char ***firstName, char ***lastName, double **scores,
           int *numberPeople)
{
  // the index we will use
  int i = *numberPeople;
  // add one to the number of people
  (*numberPeople)++;

  // expand the arrays - you should check for NULL returns here
  *firstName = realloc (*firstName, *numberPeople * sizeof (char *));
  *lastName = realloc (*lastName, *numberPeople * sizeof (char *));
  *scores = realloc (*scores, *numberPeople * sizeof (char *));

  // allocate memory for the new first and last name to live in
  *firstName[i] = malloc (MAXIMUM_DATA_LENGTH * sizeof (char));
  *lastName[i] = malloc (MAXIMUM_DATA_LENGTH * sizeof (char));

  printf ("Adding New Person....\n\n");

  printf ("First Name of new person: ");
  // your format string should be amended to limit the input length to MAXIMUM_DATA_LENGTH - 1
  // and you should check for errors
  scanf ("%s", newFirstName[i]);

  printf ("Last Name of new person: ");
  // your format string should be amended to limit the input length to MAXIMUM_DATA_LENGTH - 1
  // and you should check for errors
  scanf ("%s", newLastName[i]);

  printf ("Score of new person: ");
  // you should check for errors
  scanf ("%lf", &newScores[i]);
}
```

Comment: I'm iterating `i = *numberPeople - 1; i < *numberPeople` because when I add the new person, I add it to the new index right before the loop ends.

Comment: @David A loop is used to run code more than once. If your code only needs to run once (which in this case it does; the condition only holds for the first value of `i`), there's no point in having the loop.

Comment: @David you don't need the loop because you are meant to be adding a single entry at index `*numPeople-1`. You also don't need to `realloc()` anything to add these entries. You to *allocate* them somehow, but these `realloc()`s are freeing `firstName` and `lastName` which are the whole arrays (yes, you can use `realloc()` to allocate technically, but not like that).